# Getting undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass even when the instance variable is defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to call a controller action at two different places.

The **controller** is as follows:

```
def create
      @phone_number = PhoneNumber.find_or_create_by(phone_number: params[:phone_number][:phone_number])
      @phone_number.generate_pin
      @phone_number.send_pin
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js # render app/views/phone_numbers/create.js.erb
      end
end
```

I am trying to call `create` on a link in view:

```
  <%=link_to "Resend Pin", phone_numbers_path, method: :post %>
```

My **rake routes** output looks like this:

```
phone_numbers POST /phone_numbers(.:format)        phone_numbers#create
new_phone_number GET  /phone_numbers/new(.:format)    phone_numbers#new
phone_numbers_verify POST /phone_numbers/verify(.:format) phone_numbers#verify
```

I have data in `PhoneNumber` activerecord. When I click on "Resend Pin" I am getting following error:

```
NoMethodError in PhoneNumbersController#create
```

`undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass`

Can somebody please tell me what am I missing here ?

**html.erb**

```
<div id="send-pin">
  <h3>What's your phone number?</h3>
  <%= form_for @phone_number, remote: true do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.text_field :phone_number %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit "Send PIN", class: "btn btn-primary", id: 'send-pin-link' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div id="verify-pin">
  <h3>Enter your PIN</h3>
  <%= form_tag phone_numbers_verify_path, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'hidden_phone_number', '' %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= text_field_tag :pin %>
    </div>
    <%= submit_tag "Verify PIN", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>

  <%=link_to "Resend Pin", phone_numbers_path, method: :post  %>

</div>
```

Comment: `params[:phone_number]` is `nil` inside your create action. You need to pass it with the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params[:phone_number][:phone_number]` is null.

Try the below in view

```
<div id="send-pin">
<h3>What's your phone number?</h3>
<%= form_for @phone_number, remote: true, html: {id: "first_form"} do |f| %>

<div class="form-group">
<%= f.text_field :phone_number %>
</div>
<%= f.submit "Send PIN", class: "btn btn-primary", id: 'send-pin-link' %>
<% end %>
</div>
<div id="verify-pin">
<h3>Enter your PIN</h3>
<%= form_tag phone_numbers_verify_path, remote: true do |f| %>
<%= hidden_field_tag 'hidden_phone_number', '' %>
<div class="form-group">
<%= text_field_tag :pin %>
</div>
<%= submit_tag "Verify PIN", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>

<%=link_to "Resend Pin",'#', id: "resend_pin_code" %> 
</div>

<div id="status-box" class="alert alert-success">
<p id="status-message">Status: Haven’t done anything yet</p>
</div>


<script>
$("#resend_pin_code").click(function(){
$("#first_form").submit();
}
)
</script>
```

Comment: like this ?` `<%=link_to "Resend Pin", phone_numbers_path, method: :post, (params[:phone_number][:phone_number])  %>`
`

Comment: no, not exactly like this, can you paste your html/erb code so that I can give you the corrrect code?

Comment: Added. The link `Resend Pin` is in the last line.

Comment: Please check.. I have updated the question with view code.

Comment: where is phone_number field

Comment: For now, you can use <%=link_to "Resend Pin", phone_numbers_path(phone_number: 1312312313), method: :post  %>  & in the controller use params[:phone_number] instead of params[:phone_number][:phone_number]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143087/discussion-between-chakreshwar-sharma-and-user3576036).